# Ext JS add listener to button dynamically added

Tags: extjs

I have added buttons to a toolbar dynamically and now I am trying to add a listener that will replace the center window panel.  I am having trouble hooking up the listener in viewcontroller.

This is how I have done it so far.
Can someone point me in the direction of the proper way to do this?

```
init: function () {

    var dynamicMenu = [];

    var me = this;
    console.log(me);
    console.log(this.view);
    var myToolbar = this.view.down('toolbar');
    console.log(myToolbar);

    this.getViewModel().data.mainmenuv4store.load(function (records) {

        console.log('hit load section');

        Ext.each(records, function (record) {

            //add individual button
            var myButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: record.get('text'),
                iconCls: record.get('iconCls'),
                iconAlign: 'left',
                listeners: {
                    click: {
                        fn: function (event, target) {
                            me.selectMenuButton(event, target);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            myButton.on({
                click: 
            });

            //add button to menu array
            dynamicMenu.push(myButton);
        });

        //put this in storeLoad  otherwise this section will be hit before loading everything
        myToolbar.add(dynamicMenu);

    });
},

selectMenuButton: function (event, target) {

    Ext.Msg.alert('hi');

    var targetCmp = Ext.get(target);
    var id = targetCmp.getAttribute('text');
}
```

I changed my code to the below.  Did I set this up efficiently?

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.controller.MainMenuV4ViewController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.mainmenuv4vc',
views: [
    'ExtApplication1.view.main.MainMenuV4View'
],

init: function () {

    var dynamicMenu = [];

    var me = this;
    console.log(me);
    console.log(this.view);
    var myToolbar = this.view.down('toolbar');
    console.log(myToolbar);

    this.getViewModel().data.mainmenuv4store.load(function (records) {

        console.log('hit load section');

        Ext.each(records, function (record) {

            //add individual button
            var myButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: record.get('text'),
                iconCls: record.get('iconCls'),
                iconAlign: 'left',
                handler: me.selectMenuButton, scope: me
            });

            //add button to menu array
            dynamicMenu.push(myButton);
        });

        //put this in storeLoad  otherwise this section will be hit before loading everything
        myToolbar.add(dynamicMenu);

    });

    //listeners: {
    //    click: 'onProjectSelect'
    //    //click: {
    //    //    fn: function (event, target) {
    //    //        me.selectMenuButton(event, target);
    //    //    }
    //    //}
    //}
},

selectMenuButton: function (event, target) {

    //Ext.Msg.alert('select menu button method hit');

    console.log('select menu button section was hit')
    console.log(event);
    console.log(target);

}
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Why are you trying to bind a second click listener?

Comment: I was just trying different ways to add a listener.  I only need to bind one.  The issue is I am just looking for the proper way to bind a listener to a dynamic button, but to move the code outside of where the button is created... just for cleanness sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on the question, it looks like you want a cleaner way to establish the listener.  This is slightly cleaner:

Instead of listeners: {...}, use

```
handler: Ext.Function.bind(me.selectMenuButton, me)
```

Comment: Or use `{handler: me.selectButton, scope: me}`.

Comment: thanks, where can I go to get a good description of how handler or function.bind works... like how did you know to use those parameters?

Comment: I changed my code and put it in original post... did I do it the proper way?  one last thing... how would I have known to structure the handler the way you indicated? (with me.selectButton and scope:me?

Comment: I feel like in my selectMenuButton: function(event, target), my parameters are reversed.  Do I have it backwards?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler

Comment: thanks... I found the parameter section in your link